# jQuery function run when clicking on anchor with a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I would like a function to run when a specific anchor with the `value="frb" is clicked.

This is the anchor

```
<a href="<?php echo $l1; ?>" value="frb" class="button">Accept</a>
```

this is what i tried:

```
$('body').on('click', value[frb], function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

this doesnt work, i cant find any examples that use this, is it possible?

Comment: i don't think you should use value attribute in a link element. Maybe you should use class="frb"

Comment: @DavidCheung is there a specific reason i shouldn't?  The class it already uses is being used to css reasons.

Comment: I don't think that 'value' is a valid attribute on an 'a' tag. I haven't seen it used before.

Comment: you can add the class as a span. i.e. <span class="frb"><a href....></a></span> it wouldn't make your jquery anymore complicated

Comment: An `a` element has no `value` attribute, as already mentioned, but rather than repurposing the `class` attribute, why not simply use a custom `data-*` attribute?

Comment: I don't know if they're using html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is not valid attribute to anchor tag. Instead of that you can use `data-value` like following:

***HTML***

```
<a href="<?php echo $l1; ?>" data-value="frb" class="button">Accept</a>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[data-value=frb]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
    alert( this.href );
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vrYNy/2/)**

#### Note:

Already [**@Musa**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353011/musa) mentioned about `data` attribute, but in his jQuery snippet used `a[value=frb]` which will not work.

Comment: What is the difference between `$('body').on('click', 'a[data-value=frb]', fn);` and `$('a[data-value=frb]').on('click', fn);`?

Comment: @st-boost first one is for delegate event bing (aka live event) and second one is ordinary binding when element already exists in dom at page load

Comment: ok, thanks. Wouldn't the first method be considerably less efficient? Or does it only apply to nodes added by jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be a selector string

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[value=frb]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

also `a` tag doesn't have a value attribute, you should use a data attribute instead

```
<a href="<?php echo $l1; ?>" data-value="frb" class="button">Accept</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[value=frb]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It assigns the function to all anchors with the specified 'value' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/KQy36/

**OR** http://jsfiddle.net/WP7JS/

API: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Oh by the way: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp (To see valid `a` tag attribute)

Anyhoo, Hope this helps,

**code**

```
$('a[value="frb"]').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('yeah wha?');
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

**OR** apart of another post below mine. `:)`

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {

    if ($(this).attr("value") === "frb") {
        alert('yeah wha? I am frb');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {

        alert('not frb');
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no value attribute for the link tag we need to make a change to the html:

```
<span class="frb"><a href="<?php echo $l1; ?>" class="button">Accept</a></span>
```

Then add this to register the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.frb').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```